# Use pythonic config file in C++

Tags: python, c++, config

I'm thinking about making a "pythonic" config file where my existing static config files can be somewhat scripted i.e,:

```
setting1=1
setting2=foo
```

...and in my C++ code I read setting1 and setting2.

Would be nice to be able to basically evaluate this setting file like:

```
setting1=1
setting2='foo%d' % setting1
```

...then being able to read setting1 as 1 and setting2 as "foo1"

Was thinking about using Python.h and executing the config file as a python script and somehow iterating through all local variables and pulling them out?  Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

Comment: As unadvanced as it seems, parsing is a bunch of if's and else's. With this, I'd suggest getting the line, finding the equal, getting the left half with substr, and the right half with substr, then parse the right half according to the rules you want.

Comment: @David do you mean evaluating this stuff in C++ and not the python interpreter itself?

Comment: Embedding python in C/C++ is pretty well documented: https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html